# Get also count when sorting with query builder in Syfmony2

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

With the following query I'm getting a list of brands from a table. Only some brands there are multiple times in the database. Would it be possible to get also the count back of the brands together with its name?

```
   return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a.brand')
        ->where('a.active = 1')
        ->OrderBy('a.brand', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```php
return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->select('a.brand, count(a.brand) as brandCount')
    ->where('a.active = 1')
    ->groupBy('a.brand')
    ->OrderBy('a.brand', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```